# Subspace Topology and Limit Points

Tags: general-topology

Trying to show that for every positive integers $i,j$ there is a set $A_{i,j}\subseteq[0,1]$ ($[0,1]$ has the Subspace Topology from $\mathbb{R}_\text{std.}$) such that $|A^{(i)}|=j$ and $|A^{(i+1)}|=\emptyset$, where $A^{(m)}$ denotes the $m$th order limit points. I would show my attempted solution(s), however, I really have no idea how to start such a problem. The $m$th order limit points means: $A^{(1)} = A'$, $A^{(2)} = (A')'$, and so on.

Comment: Excuse, may I ask something? What's the order of a limit point?

Comment: @Dog_69 For example, $A^{(1)} = A'$, $A^{(2)} = (A')'$, and so on. Maybe there is a better word for it... I will make an edit and add this in.

Comment: HINT: $A_{1,1}$ is easy. Once you have it, try to add points to it to get $A_{2,1}$. Do it again to get $A_{3,1}$. At that point you may be able to come up with a general description of how to construct $A_{n,1}$ for $n\ge 1$. To get $A_{n,m}$ for $m>1$, divide $[0,1]$ into $m$ closed intervals and construct a shrunken copy of $A_{n,1}$ in each of them.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott would $A_{1,1}:= \{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a good choice?

Comment: @Dalton: Yes, except that you need to throw in $0$ to get your limit point.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I understand the premise of the solution (based of your hint), however, I am having trouble trying to think of how to construct the next couple set...i.e. $A_{2,1}$.

Comment: @Dalton: I suggest switching from $\frac1n$ to $\frac1{2^n}$; that will make the later steps easier. Now you want a sequence that converges down to $\frac1{2^n}$. If you start it at $\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^{n+1}}$, the next point should be $\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^{n+2}}$, then $\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^{n+3}}$, and so on. Basically it’s the original geometric sequence multiplied by $\frac1{2^{n+1}}$ and shifted to the right by $\frac1{2^n}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So, take $A_{1,1}:=\{\frac{1}{2^n}\}$, $A_{2,1}:=\{\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\}$, $A_{3,1}:=\{\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n+3}}\}$, ...., $A_{n,1}:=\{\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n+n}}\}$?

Comment: @Dalton: Yep. And I’ve gone ahead and written up these comments (plus a bit) as an actual answer, since they’re getting fairly extensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SKETCH: Let $A_{1,1}=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1{2^n}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$. To get $A_{2,1}$, we add a sequence converging downward to each $\frac1{2^n}$. Show that this can be done by adding the points $\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^{n+m}}$ for $n,m\in\Bbb Z^+$. For $A_{3,1}$  add points $\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^{n+m}}+\frac1{2^{n+m+k}}$ for $n,m,k\in\Bbb Z^+$ and show that this works. At this point the general construction should be clear, as well as how to see that it works.

It may be helpful to think in binary. Apart from $0$, the points of $A_{1,1}$ are $0.1_2$, $0.01_2$, $0.001_2$, and in general all of the numbers in $[0,1)$ whose binary expansions contain a single $1$. The new points in $A_{2,1}$ are those numbers in $[0,1)$ whose binary expansions contain exactly two $1$s, and in general the points of $A_{n+1,1}\setminus A_{n,1}$ are those numbers in $[0,1)$ whose binary expansions contain exactly $n+1$ $1$s.

Once you have all of the sets $A_{n,1}$, you can get $A_{n,m}$ by starting with $$\bigcup_{k=0}^{m-1}(A_{n,1}+k)\,,$$ where $A+k=\{a+k:a\in A\}$, and multiplying it by $\frac1m$.

Comment: This is great! Did you mean to write $A_{1,n}$ in the union? Or is it suppose to be $A_{n,1}$?

Comment: @Dalton: I had a bunch of them reversed and missed that one when I was fixing them; thanks!

Comment: So, would the final set be $A_{n,m}:= \bigcup_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{m}\left( A_{n,1} + k \right)$, where $A_{n,1}:= \{\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n+n}}\}$?

Comment: @Dalton: Unless I’ve slipped up somewhere, that should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was taken from an old qualifying exam I'm using to review, so I will need to look over this more carefully, thanks again!

Comment: @Dalton: You’re welcome!

Comment: Hey Brian, do you know how the sets $A_{n,m}$ can be used to show that there are $|2^{\omega}|$, i.e. continuum, many pairwise non-homeomorphic countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}_{std.}$? I suppose I would want to use the fact that if two spaces are homeomorphic then the cardinality of the set of limit points would be the same, but I am not sure how to use this any further...

Comment: @Dalton: I’ll have to think about doing it with these sets. In the meantime, **Lemma** $\bf{4.7}$ in [this PDF](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.vanmill/papers/papers2014/2pointsets.pdf) does the job a little differently.

Comment: @Dalton: For $\varnothing\ne S\subseteq\Bbb Z^+$ let $$X_S=\bigcup_{n\in S}\Big((A_{n,1}+2n)\cup(\Bbb Q\cap(2n-1,2n)\big)\Big)\,;$$ the ‘deepest’ limit points of the $|S|$ pieces are identifiable because they do not have any compact nbhds, and the set of ‘depths’ (Cantor-Bendixson ranks) of these points is a topological invariant.

Comment: Interesting, i’m sure your solution is correct, but where i’m at in my text (which corresponds to this problem), we haven’t yet covered compactness nor Cantor-Bendixson ranks (which i don’t think is covered at all in the text which corresponds to the problem).

Comment: @Dalton: You don’t actually need C-B ranks; here they just correpond to the number of times you have to take the set of limit points to get down to a singleton. You don’t need compactness, either: the ‘deepest’ points — the ones that you need to be able to identify topologically — are also the only ones with the property that every open nbhd of the point contains a set with no isolated points.

Comment: So, the ‘deepest’ limit points of the $|S|$ pieces are the $m$th order limit points?

Comment: @Dalton: Yes, the single points of the sets $A_{n,1}$ that remain when you no longer have any limit points left.

Comment: I am having trouble seeing the big picture here, i.e. how does the set $X_{S}$ help prove the claim?

Comment: @Dalton: If $S$ and $T$ are distinct subsets of $\Bbb Z^+$, $X_S$ and $X_T$ are not homeomorphic: any homeomorphism preserves depth and also preserves the property that every nbhd of a point contains an open set with no isolated points.

Comment: I see that part now, however, how does this imply continuum many paits?

Comment: @Dalton: $\Bbb Z^+$ has $2^\omega$ different subsets $S$, and each gives rise to a distinct space $X_S$ not homeomorphic to any $X_T$ for $T\in\wp(\Bbb Z^+)\setminus\{S\}$.

Comment: Brian, thank you so much for your time! May I ask, where did the intuition for the set $X_S$ come from?

Comment: @Dalton: You’re most welcome! That’s a hard question to answer, because the most honest short answer is probably *experience*, but perhaps I can give at least some idea of what was in the back of my mind. You had got me thinking about how to use the sets from this problem; there are only countably many of them, but that means that there are $2^\omega$ different *sets* of them, so all that I had to do then was work out how to combine an arbitrary set of them in such a way that they could be recovered.